# How to increase the outgoing HTTP requests quota in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, concurrency

I'm trying to send high volume HTTP requests from a machine. But it seems that .NET Core, or Windows I don't know, is restricting the number of concurrent HTTP requests that can go out, or the quota of HTTP requests in a given time fraction.

How can I increase this? I remember that we had a configuration in .NET Framework, but I'm unable to find that either.

Comment: Can you post your configurations in .net framework

Comment: As I said, I'm working in .NET Core now.

Comment: you said that the configurations is working in .net framework, I want to see the configuration to help you mapping it to .net core.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem .NET configuration doesn't affect how many concurrent requests can be made.

Comment: In .net core no limitation regarding to number of concurrent connections.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem yes there is, the same as .NET Framework. The way you change it is different though

Comment: I said I remember that we had something in .NET Framework, and as I said I can't find it either.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli are you using HttpClient to make those calls? What does your code look like? There are duplicate questions about this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, `HttpClient` is what I use.

Comment: To be a *good citizen on the net*, there are usually limitations set on the number of concurrent requests *per host* that you should make. Outside of e.g. building a perfomance testing tool or other specialised circumstances, you should respect the default.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, how to increase that default?

Comment: Related: [What is HttpClient's default maximum connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735569/what-is-httpclients-default-maximum-connections)

Answer (score 19):

The HTTP 1.1 protocol advised that only 2 concurrent requests should be made per domain. Both the .NET Framework and .NET Core use this limit for desktop applications. ASP.NET applications have a limit of 10 concurrent requests. Both runtimes allow you to change the limit.

This limit made sense for browsers a while ago but it's too restrictive for service oriented applications. Browsers allow around 8 concurrent connections nowadays and service/REST applications can handle more.

[ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netcore-2.2) can be used to change the limit for the entire application, eg :

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

You can also specify a limit per `HttpClient` instance, by using an `HttpClientHandler` with the [HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netcore-2.2) property set to the desired limit :

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    MaxConnectionsPerServer= 100,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

This way you can set different limits per target service.

**Don't rush and set the limit to a huge number**. The target services may *not* be able to handle 20 or 40 concurrent requests from the same client. Badly written services may crash or flood the server. Concurrent requests may block each other, *reducing* the actual throughput. Well written services may impose a rate limit per client, or queue requests.

You'd be surprised how *badly* some supposedly high-traffic services behave. I've encountered airline services that could crash if more than just *10* concurrent requests were made over a minute. Badly configured load balancers would *still* direct traffic to those crashed services for at least 1-2 minutes until the service restarted, making retries meaningless.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netframework-4.7.2 HttpClient MaxConnectionPerserver is now Int32.MaxValue. 
When I check with reflection at net framework 4.8 it was also int max shown.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288402/2483016) as this is a similar case. Generally you have ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to change the limit. 
I'm also encouraging you to do this with great caution as you can also hit the [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) limit or create high load on the target server.